# Oracle XML - How to escape text between tags.

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

If i have a CLOB column with the following xml document

```
<xml>
<Country>Trinidad & Tobago </Country>
</xml>
```

I want to escape the ampersand but not the tags.

I know i can use this approach:

```
Select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(country) from country_list;
```

The above query escapes all the special characters. i.e. `< > and &.` Is there a way i can only escape anything that is between the  tags. I.e. the output after escaping is

```
<xml>
<Country>Trinidad &amp; Tobago </Country>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in a manner similar to the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COUNTRY,
                      '(<.*>.*)(&)(.*</.*>)',
                      '\1&amp;\3') AS REPLACEMENT_TEXT
  FROM COUNTRY_LIST;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf6bc/1)

Share and enjoy.